# Visible/hide div with jquery when checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, hidden, visible

I have a script that makes **a div visible or hidden when I check a checkbox** (works perfectly). For example: product has discount *check* --> show div to enter a discount price.

When loading the detail page, the checkbox is checked/unchecked according to the property "isAvailable". **When it's checked by default, it doesn't show the div!** Unless you click on the checkbox twice and check it manually.

This is my script:

```
   $("#DiscountCheckbox").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                document.getElementById("percentageDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
                $("#percentageDiv").fadeIn(200);
            }
            else {
                $("#percentageDiv").fadeOut(200);
                document.getElementById("percentageDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        });
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.Product.Price.IsActive, new { @class = "filled-in", id = "DiscountCheckbox" })
  <label for="DiscountCheckbox" title="Add a discount to this product">add discount</label>
</div>

<!-- div that is visible/hidden -->
<div class="form-group" id="percentageDiv">
<label class="control-label" for="txtboxCustomerRef">Discount name:</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Discount.DiscountName, new { placeholder = "enter discount name", @class = "form-control", id = "DiscountName", title = "Enter a name for this discount" })
</div>
```

I tried to set this in de document ready but didn't work for me, maybe I didn't do it right:

```
     $(function () {
        if ($("#DiscountCheckbox").is(':checked')) {
            document.getElementById("percentageDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
            $("#percentageDiv").fadeIn(200);
        }
        else {
            $("#percentageDiv").fadeOut(200);
            document.getElementById("percentageDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }


    });
```

Comment: can you share the html code because the html code you jave given is not understand

Comment: @bhanusengar Can you tell me what you need because this is the html code I use.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code to $(document).ready(){}
in propet way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if ($("#DiscountCheckbox").is(':checked')) {
        document.getElementById("percentageDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
        $("#percentageDiv").fadeIn(200);
    }
    else {
        $("#percentageDiv").fadeOut(200);
        document.getElementById("percentageDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }});
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, tried it again (as you suggested) but still not working. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work. Yes, it is visible and checked by default but when unchecking it stays visible. Not what I am looking for + my example **is working** when manually checking/unchecking. Only checking it by default when the page is loaded for the first time, it doesn't show. Seems the .change function is not triggered, for clarification: everything works manually, checking/unchecking after it's loaded always works, only the first time doesn't.

Comment: @Famke my code shows answer on your problem with default checked/unchecked.
And its works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**This will help you to understand**

**HTML**

```
<label for="chkPassport">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkPassport" />
    Do you have Passport?
</label>
<hr />
<div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
    Passport Number:
    <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber" />
</div>
<div id="AddPassport">
    Add New Password
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function () {
        $("#chkPassport").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#dvPassport").show();
                $("#AddPassport").hide();
            } else {
                $("#dvPassport").hide();
                $("#AddPassport").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

**I hope it will work for you.**

Comment: First of all, thank you! I have tried the .show & .hide functions but it doesn't work even for the manual check/uncheck, and it doesn't work on the document ready either. When manually checking/unchecking the div pops open but the content of it stays hidden while the .style.visibility = "visible/hidden" does work manually. Could it be that when checking the checkbox with the property's value, wich happens on the page rendering, that the jquery on change isn't triggered? I'm kind of lost here.. Any help or suggestions are appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

**I found the problem!** 
The Jquery I was using wasn't the issue. Manually checking/unchecking the checkbox perfectly shows and hides the (Discount)-Div. But not when my page was loaded for the first time.

So I tried several ways to do the check on a document ready but that didn't work. I started digging into my code and came to following conclusion: the div that needs to be visible/hidden is **inside another div that has tabs on top**. The check had to be done **when clicking on that specific tab!** I didn't think of this AT ALL.. Thought that couldn't be an issue..

Here you can see all of the script I use now:

```
<script>
    $("#DiscountCheckbox").change(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        document.getElementById("percentageDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
                        $("#percentageDiv").fadeIn(200);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#percentageDiv").fadeOut(200);
                        document.getElementById("percentageDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    }
                });
            $("#tabPrices").click(function () {
                if ($("#DiscountCheckbox").is(':checked')) {
                    document.getElementById("percentageDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
                    $("#percentageDiv").fadeIn(200);
                }

                else {
                    $("#percentageDiv").fadeOut(200);
                    document.getElementById("percentageDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }

            });
    </script>
```